# Possible to add image caption with css pseudo content?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I am looking for the easiest, most maintainable way to do this:

[image]

These are text slugs that will be appended to certain images throughout the site. They all say this same thing, but the images are varied and come from a CMS.

I know how I would do it with the image set to position relative and a div with "there's a better way" in an absolutely positioned child div.

However, since that requires HTML added to every image that gets this treatment, I was looking for a way to do this with a css class using the :before pseudo element.  So far, applying the class to a wrapping link has no effect:

```
<a href="#" class="tabw"><img src="imagepath" alt=""></a>

.tabw img:before {
content: 'theres a better way';
color: red;
font-size: 18px;
}
```

Is this sort of thing possible?  Having the whole thing in CSS means all I have to do is have the CMS apply the class attribute when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, `::before` and `::after` don't work on images. But you can apply them to the wrapper 
link:

```
a{
  position: relative;
}

a, a > img{
  display:inline-block;
}

a::before{
  content: 'theres a better way';
  position: absolute;    
  left: 0;
  top: 0;     
  width: 80%;
  height: 20px;
  left: 10%;  
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.4;      
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yHqE6/)

If you want the text added in the HTML, you'll have to put a real element with it in your link (and apply the same rules to it, but without `content`)

Comment: I didn't realize about images and pseudo elements.  It was driving me crazy.  This is exactly what I was trying to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it like this with jQuery :

**Html**

```
<div class="thumb">
    <img src="http://www.zupmage.eu/up/NvBtxn7LHl.png" alt="cover"/>
    <div class="caption">My caption</div>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.thumb {
    position:relative;
    width:230px;
    height:230px;
}

.thumb img {
    max-width:100%;
}

.thumb .caption {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.thumb').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.caption').hide();
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/zm937/)

Comment: Thanks, but it's a bit too involved.  Also, if I was going to add the extra div in the html, I could accomplish this without the jquery.  I was looking for a solution that kept the caption content in the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE TO ANYONE FINDING THIS THREAD:**  In Firefox 21 and IE 9/10 this did not work right with oversized images.  It forced the images to 100% even if globally set to max-width: 100%

I had to follow the answer I selected above **but** set the A tag to `display:block` instead of `display:inline-block` to fix.